# error when iterating a list of floats in python3

Tags: python

I am a Python3 newbie.. I am trying to figure out why this does not work.

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thur', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']

hours = []
count = 0

while count < 6:
    print('Please tell me how many hours you slept on:')
    for day in days:
        print(day)
        value = float(input())
        hours.append(value)
        v = sum(value)
        count = count + 1

avg =  ((v) / 7)

print("you slept an average of", round(avg), 'hours')
```

When I run this I get the following error: "TypeError 'float' object is not iterable" the traceback references line 18 'v = sum(value)'

thank you

Comment: What are you summing? `value` (one single float) or `hours` (a list of floats)?

Comment: I want to sum the list of floats I get from the user input.

Comment: And what are you _actually_ summing in your code? Hint: look at  `v = sum(value)`.

Comment: Set v as a variable at the top and do v += value. Then get rid of sum ()

Comment: Rakesh thank you! your question made me realize my code was summing the "single float" from input vs what I wanted to do .. sum the values in my list .. thank you again!

Comment: Thank you all! i learned from my mistake LOL

Comment: Set v as 0 at the top and where it says v = sum (value) change it to v = v +  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
v = sum(value)
```

to

```
v = sum(hours)    #sum the list of sleep hrs
```